# Can you please provide the meaning of Hanuman Vadvanal Stotra in English and explain its benefits?

Tags: hanuman, stotra, vibhishana

Please provide the line by line meaning of Vadvanal Stotra in English along with the benefits. Thank you.

Comment: The benefits can be directly known from stotra. But the important one is: can be recited to lower down the fever. I guess a complete translation might get off topic here.